# Repository can not be reached with xcode 4.2

Tags: iphone, ios4, xcode4, osx-lion

I have application which is configured with svn and its working fine in my xcode 4.1 but i just updated my xcode with xcode 4.2.

now i am getting error that "Repository can not be reached" and i am not able to use svn from xcode 4.2.

Comment: I use GIT and no luck with the organizer either. I'm able to commit to the local repository, then have to push/pull via command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting burned by this as well. That said I've found a workaround using XCode 4 to check files back in to svn.
Instead of using the Project Navigator, use the Organizer:

Choose the folder containing the project you checked out of your svn repository.
At the bottom of the Organizer window, click on the "Commit" icon.
Select the files you want to check in and add your comment.

Answer (score 4):

This is going to sound stupid, but I was able to get around this with only a few simple steps:

1. Open Safari and make sure the certificate for your repository has been accepted permanently
2. Quit XCode
3. Restart XCode

I don't know why this worked, but all I can say is XCode is weird.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. i have fixed this issue with xcode update. In xcode 4.6, i am  not facing this issue.

Comment: Surprisingly this fixed the issue for me as well